# REGEX for finding pos tags in a list

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a list of sentences which I have converted to pos tags such as:

```
tags = 
[['DET', 'ADJ', 'NOUN', 'VERB', 'ADP', 'ADJ', 'ADJ', 'NOUN', 'ADP','DET', 'NOUN', 'ADJ', 'AUX', 'PUNCT']
['DET','NOUN', 'VERB', 'ADP', 'ADJ', 'ADJ', 'NOUN', 'ADP', 'DET','NOUN', 'PUNCT']]
```

I am trying to create a regex like this:

1. one DET to start
2. zero or one ADJ next
3. one NOUN next
4. one VERB next
5. Anything else in between
6. final position should be one NOUN followed by PUNCT

So for example it would except:

```
['DET','NOUN', 'VERB', 'ADP', 'ADJ', 'ADJ', 'NOUN', 'ADP', 'DET','NOUN', 'PUNCT']

['DET','ADJ', 'NOUN', 'VERB', 'DET', 'NOUN', 'ADP', 'DET','NOUN', 'PUNCT']
```

but it would not accept:

```
['DET', 'ADJ', 'NOUN', 'VERB', 'ADP', 'ADJ', 'ADJ', 'NOUN', 'ADP','DET', 'NOUN', 'ADJ', 'AUX', 'PUNCT']


['ADJ', 'NOUN', 'VERB', 'ADP', 'AUX', 'PUNCT']
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I hate when people down vote items and give no reason as to why. Personally I find this interesting. I've limited exp with regex but to me and my limited knowledge it would seem that the source content would have to first be parsed with a program to convert all of the values to the tag basis and then you could run it against the regex but then would need to take the findings of the regex to then run another program to identify the content in the source data.

Comment: @Elijah, yes I hate it too. I don't post bad questions on purpose and so if it is not an acceptable question I'd happily change it or know better for next time if people would say what the problem is, but what can you do? Anyway, after way too long on this task I might have to admit defeat and forget about it. I just thought I would post it here to see if anyone had any similar experience.

Comment: Just so I'm clear on this, you're kind of wanting to read in text content and look for grammar patterns

Comment: @Elijah, its somewhat complicated, I have a list of software requirements, I have pos tagged them, so I have a list of pos tagged sentences. I am then trying to determine which of the requirements adhere to a template. The template is what I posted above (the rules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is! This regex should do what you're looking for.

`^\['DET',\s?(?:'ADJ',\s?)?'NOUN',\s?'VERB'\s?.*'NOUN',\s?'PUNCT'\]$`

- `^\[` Start the regex with an open brace, anchored to the start of string
- `'DET',\s?` Get a `'DET',` with an optional space after it. You can remove the `\s?` if you know your list won't have any spaces between entries - there were a few inconsistencies in spacing in your examples, so I added this to handle it.
- `(?:'ADJ',\s?)?` Put an `'ADJ',` in a capture group, and make it optional.
- `'NOUN',\s?'VERB'\s?` One noun, one verb. The `\s?` isn't required due to the wildcard in the next piece, but it's here for readability's sake.
- `.*` Anything! This wildcard captures as much as it can.
- `'NOUN',\s?'PUNCT'` End with a noun and punctuation.
- `\]$` Finish the regex with a close bracket, anchored at the end of the string.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/EgG4qK/2/)